# What is meaning of MOS 3060 in 1950-1952 documents from US Army service?

Tags: united-states, military-records, 1950s

I have 1950-1952 documents from a relative's US Army service.

What is the meaning of MOS 3060?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ARMY | BCMR | CY2004 | 20040005186C070208](http://upgrade.vet/vetup/detail/ARMY/BCMR/CY2004/20040005186C070208), it appears your relative (like the person that page is about) may have:

> served in military occupational specialty (MOS) 3060 (Cook).

Comment: This does answer the question as edited.  :-)  How did you happen to find that?  All my searches turned up today's MOS's which apparently are two digits and a letter.

Comment: It was the fourth record returned when I typed ["MOS 3060"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22MOS+3060%22&oq=%22MOS+3060%22&aqs=edge.0.69i59j69i64.5231j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) into Google's search bar

Comment: Interesting.  DuckDuckGo gave me only pages showing recent digit-digit-letter MOSs.

Comment: The bulk of results on DuckDuckGo actually come from Bing and Yahoo, which is why Google often turns up results that DDG misses.  See the section on [sources](https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/sources/) from the DDG help pages for more info.